# Jbutton selection criteria

Tags: java, jradiobutton

I am designing a Java project which contains a Radio button group having 15 jRadio buttons. Each Radio button have names like "Master", "Front_desk", "Accounts" etc. and this text name is defined in MySQL table. In MySQL table I have defined whether to enable or disable particular radio button. I use following code to get Radio button name from MySQL table

```
String Btn_name = Rs.getString("Module_name");
```

after get Btn_name I tried to enable or disable the radio button state by using follwing command

```
Btn_name.setEnabled(true);
```

or

```
Btn_name.setEnabled(false);
```

but I am getting following error

```
can not find symbol
symbol : method setEnabled(boolean)
location : variable Btn_name of type String
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a jradiobutton in a standard way,

```
JRadioButton btn = new JRadioButton().
btn.setText(Btn_name);
btn.setEnabled(true/false);
```

And create as many jradiobutton you need in a loop over the resultSet.